# Db Generic Resource Authorization

Tags: c#, entity-framework, authorization, .net-core, filtering

I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically authorize my context based on a role.

```
public interface IConstraintResolver
{
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>[] GetConstraintsForTypeByRole<TEntity>() 
        where TEntity : class;
}
public class AuthorizationContext : DbContext
{
    protected IConstraintResolver _constraintResolver;
    public AuthorizationContext(IConstraintResolver constraintResolver)
    {
        this._constraintResolver = constraintResolver;
    }

    public override DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>()
    {
        var defaultSet = base.Set<TEntity>();

        var constraints = this._constraintResolver.GetConstraintsForTypeByRole<TEntity>();

        var filteredSet = base.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();

        foreach(var constraint in constraints)
        {
            filteredSet = filteredSet.Where(constraint);
        }

        //how do I apply this back to the innerQueryable
        return filteredSet;
    }
}
```

My issue is that after applying my queryable how can I make this the default queryable for the Set.

I found a gyst which works with the old DbSet [here](https://gist.github.com/bengavin/e75d5759b4941176b4e51b742428bd15)

But .Net Core does not contain IDBSet

How can I create a custom dbset, or How can I filter the existing dbSet?

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov will that still work with saving and connecting to the change tracker etc.  I feel like there should be a simple way to filter this set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is better approach via [global filters](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/wiki/EF-Query-Filter-%7C-Entity-Framework-Dynamic-Instance-and-Global-Filters#ef-query-filter-global):

```
public class AuthorizationContext : DbContext
{
    static AuthorizationContext()
    {
         QueryFilterManager.Filter<Orders>(q => q.Where(x => x.Price <= 5000));
    }

    public AuthorizationContext()
    {
         QueryFilterManager.InitilizeGlobalFilter(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I need my context to filter this by default.  So the developer doesn’t need to remember to filter the context. But normally that might work so plus 1

Comment: Ok, at this case, you can use _global filters_, look at updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll investigate this tonight.  I'd prefer to include an extra dependency, but if this work it works.  I'll mark this correct tonight if it does

Comment: I'm usually inclined to write things myself but this library will save me a whole lot of time, Thanks!